# Which PHP function best suited for retrieving web server data

Tags: php, http, curl

I thought an interesting way of recording my browsing or performing certain tasks upon viewing particular websites, would be to create some sort of overlay (front end) to sit at the top of my browser view window and have PHP in the back parse web server data. These are very common for services such as script based proxies and advertising.

If I were to use PHP to save plain text copies of wikipedia articles as I view them, an offline cache if you will, which method of retrieving the data would be the most appropriate?

Using stream functions (file_get_contents, file etc..) or cURL/core PHP HTTP requests or even sockets? (although tinkering with TCP/IP wouldn't be the simplest method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **file_get_contents()** if you're only retrieving data, it's the easiest method and is always available.

If you'll need to POST data, use cURL (a php-extension so it isn't guaranteed to be enabled on your server)

Sockets are only needed if you'll need something other than http, https or ftp.
*(For supported protocols check "Registered PHP Streams" in your phpinfo)*

If you want to download a page including css, etc you might want to look into [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)
A standard linux commandline tool to download content.

```
<?php
chdir('/path/to/store/the/files/');
system('wget -E -H -k -K -p -nd http://www.example.com/'); // use passthru() instead of system if you want to see the output/errors.
?>
```

*(I don't know what all those parameters mean, i just copied this snippet from [here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/134394-wget-download-single-page.html), checkout the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/) for details)*

Comment: I'm using file_get_contents() and the minute however it obviously does not preserve relative paths to stylesheets and such, therefore narrowing the use. I could use a combination of cURL and the previous function for both requesting data as well as receiving it.

Comment: Wait a second... `file_get_contents()` always available? I thought the PHP configuration might disallow passing URL-s into this function and that actually there _are_ servers that disallow it...

Comment: Thank you very much for reminding me of wget! I forgot I used this and a few other linux commands when configuring CronJob on Cpanel.

Answer (score 1):

I saw once the a component of the Zend Framework as an http client.
I think it's the most easy and powerful to do such spider. I am trying to remeber what was its name.

It's `Zend_Http_Client`. Example:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://wiki/');
$response = $client->request(); 
print_r($response->getBody());
```

Comment: Wow I haven't seen that before. Tell me, is this normally accessible through PHP? I can't find zend_http_client in the online manual.

Comment: @Lee: you must download the Zend Framework, then include it in your application. You can find a lot more stuff usefull

Comment: +1 for this. Using a framework like Zend or CakePHP abstracts away all the heavy lifting from you so you can focus on the task at hand. I'm not sure about CakePHP but with Zend you can pick and choose which bits of the framework you use without needing to use the entire kit + caboodle.

Comment: Great, I didn't know of these things. I've only programmed with PHP and other libraries like cURL. Great comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that cURL would be your best alternative. Easy to get started with, easy to adjust to your needs and very powerful. Learn more: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: cURL in combination with an XML parser should do the same trickery.